# Difference between binary zeros and ASCII character zero

Tags: c

```
gcc (GCC) 4.8.1
c89
```

Hello,

I was reading a book about pointers. And using this code as a sample:

```
memset(buffer, 0, sizeof buffer);
```

Will fill the buffer will binary zero and not the character zero.

I am just wondering what is the difference between the binary and the character zero. I thought it was the same thing.

I know that textual data is human readable characters and binary data is non-printable characters. Correct me if I am wrong.

What would be a good example of binary data?

For added example, if you are dealing with strings (textual data) you should use `fprintf`. And if you are using binary data you should use `fwrite`. If you want to write data to a file.

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Comment: It's the `'\0'` zero that you are talking about, right?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight from the question I think most probably OP means `'0'`

Comment: take a look at an ASCII table.

Comment: For example, look at http://www.cdrummond.qc.ca/cegep/informat/professeurs/alain/files/ascii.htm .  Note that the "0" character is decimal 48/hex 30, and the "1" character follows immediately after.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The quick answer is that the character `'0'` is represented in binary data by the ASCII number 48.  That means, when you want the character `'0'`, the file actually has these bits in it: `00110000`.  Similarly, the printable character `'1'` has a decimal value of 49, and is represented by the byte `00110001`.  (`'A'` is 65, and is represented as `01000001`, while `'a'` is 97, and is represented as `01100001`.)

If you want the null terminator at the end of the string, `'\0'`, that actually has a 0 decimal value, and so would be a byte of all zeroes: `00000000`.  This is truly a 0 value.  To the compiler, there is no difference between

```
memset(buffer, 0, sizeof buffer);
```

and

```
memset(buffer, '\0', sizeof buffer);
```

The only difference is a semantic one to us.  `'\0'` tells us that we're dealing with a character, while 0 simply tells us we're dealing with a number.

It would help you tremendously to check out an [ascii table](http://www.asciitable.com/).

`fprintf` outputs data using ASCII and outputs strings.  `fwrite` writes pure binary data.  If you `fprintf(fp, "0")`, it will put the value 48 in fp, while if you `fwrite(fd, 0)` it will put the actual value of 0 in the file.  (Note, my usage of `fprintf` and `fwrite` were obviously not proper usage, but shows the point.)

Note: My answer refers to ASCII because it's one of the oldest, best known character sets, but as Eric Postpichil mentions in the comments, the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf) isn't bound to ASCII.  (In fact, while it does occasionally give examples using ASCII, the standard seems to go out of its way to never assume that ASCII will be the character set used.).  `fprintf` outputs using the execution character set of your compiled program.

Comment: Please don't confuse things with `'\0'`.  The difference between `0` and `'0'` is hard enough to follow.

Comment: @HotLicks I see where you're coming from, but it seems like the asker would want to know that an all-`0` byte is `\0`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil - This is true, but to delve into that issue would only add complication at this point in the discussion.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I agree, there should be mention of character coding.  I've tried to add a note at the end, but am not thrilled with what I've put.  If you can phrase it better than I, please edit my answer.  I'll welcome the improvement.

Comment: @ScottMermelstein: The note at the end suffices. It is enough so that people who find themselves in a situation where it matters have that alternative at the back of their heads. (When trying to solve a problem, it is hard to question an assumption you do not know is an assumption, which is why I emphasize not glossing over things like this.) Were I writing an answer from scratch, I would discuss encoding characters without emphasizing ASCII. But if I tried to change an existing answer, I would be tempted to edit too much.

Comment: @EricPostpischil - If I were answering it I'd probably go back to Herman's punched cards, but I'm guessing everyone would be asleep by the time I finished.

Comment: @HotLicks You have something against [Charles' gears and plates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Difference_engine)?  (Or [cards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytical_Engine), though I just learned that none of those have have yet been built.)

Comment: @ScottMermelstein - But none of that stuff was used to represent characters.

Answer (score 2):

If you are asking about the difference between `'0'` and `0`, these two are completely different:

- Binary zero corresponds to a non-printable character `\0` (also called the null character), with the code of zero. This character serves as null terminator in C string:

> 5.2.1.2 A byte with all bits set to 0, called the *null character*, shall exist in the basic execution character set; it is used to terminate a character string.

- ASCII character zero `'0'` is printable (not surprisingly, producing a character zero when printed) and has a decimal code of 48.

Answer (score 1):

Binary zero: `0`
Character zero: `'0'`, which in [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) is `48`.

Answer (score 1):

binary data: the **raw data** that the cpu gets to play with, bit after bit, the stream of 0s and 1s (usually organized in groups of 8, aka Bytes, or multiples of 8)

character data: bytes **interpreted** as characters. Conventions like ASCII give the rules how a specific bit sequence should be displayed by a terminal, a printer, ...
for example, the binary data (bit sequence ) `00110000` should be displayed as `0`

if I remember correctly, the unsigned integer datatypes would have a direct match between the binary value of the stored bits and the interpreted value (ignore strangeness like Endian ^^).

On a higher level, for example talking about ftp transfer, the destinction is made between:

- the data should be interpreted as (multi)byte characters, aka text (this includes non-character signs like a line break)
- the data is a big bit/bytestream, that can't be broken down in smaller human readable bits, for example an image or a compiled executable

Answer (score 1):

in system every character have a code and zero ASCII code is 0x30(hex).
to fill this buffer with zero character you must enter this code :

```
memset(buffer,30,(size of buffer))
```