# Difference between '0', 0 and '\0' in a C string

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, char, printf

I got this piece of code in C but I do not understand why the output is :

**OUTPUT:** "Hell"

I would expect it to be "Hell00000000" rather then "Hell".
Could enyone please explain why there is only "Hell" ?

```
char str[666];
char * x = str + 4;
strcpy ( str, "Hello world!" );

while ( *x )
 {
   *x ++ = 0;
 }
printf ( "%s", str );
```

Comment: `0` and `'0'` are 2 different characters.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is the question which can be sorted by reading the basic string chapter in any book or tutorial.

Comment: @PeterJ_01 I disagree. The questioner is confused about the difference between `'0'`, `0` and `'\0'`. Just because it is a fairly basic problem, doesn't mean it is not suitable for Stack Overflow. It might be a duplicate of some other question though.

Comment: Check out this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17975575/difference-between-binary-zeros-and-ascii-character-zero

Comment: So the title should be : what is the difference between 0 and '0'. Number of this kind of questions is increasing exponentially.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **`\0`** and **`0`** are **same** . Both are `nul` terminating characters for the character array.

**`0`** and **`'0'`** are **different**. First one has ascii code of `0` second one has ascii code of `48`.

Here you are un-intentionally putting the nul terminating character. That's why you got `Hell`.

If you wanted to get the result `Hell00000000`

```
char str[666];
char * x = str + 4;
strcpy ( str, "Hello world!" );

while ( *x )
 {
   *x  = '0'; //<------This is different.
   x++;
 }
printf ( "%s", str );
```

Answer (score 2):

The value `0` in a string isn't a valid character (or, to be more precise, it's the `NUL` character typically representing "no character") and is used as the end-mark of a string in C.

You're confusing it with `'0'` (the **printable character**), which would be for example `48` if you're using an encoding based on ASCII.

Comment: This the classical example of the question which should be closed as the answer is in any C tutorial or book.

Comment: @PeterJ_01 that's not a close reason. A valid close reason here could be a *simple typo*, but it seems there's really some confusion. We don't grade questions the way you might think. That said, a "stupid" question might still be worth a downvote.

Comment: Should be as SO in flowed by the question showing just lack of effort and allergy to the books. It converts the SO from the programmers forum to the teaching portal for lazy OPs

Comment: @PeterJ_01 there's no objective way to measure what you're saying and I guess that's the reason we don't have a canonic "close reason" saying something like "asking about basic language knowledge". You will find a lot of questions like this in the more historic part of SO.

Answer (score 0):

You change them to `0`, that is the nul character, equals to `'\0'`. If you want to add 0 as a char, you have to use `'0'`.