# FTDI D2XX write then read, however result is empty

Tags: c++, ftdi

I am trying to get a basic example working using the D2XX driver from FTDI to write a command and read back the result.
(I am using D2XX since I want access to the FTDI eeprom user area memory).

I have included here the code, which is based on an example from the FTDI knowledge base for reading: https://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Knowledgebase/ft_read.htm

and writing and setting the parameters: https://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/TechnicalNotes/TN_153%20Instructions%20on%20Including%20the%20D2XX%20Driver%20in%20a%20VS%20Express%202013%20Project.pdf

So far when I try to read, the buffer would appear to be empty. Any help in debugging here and pointers in the right direction are much appreciated.
Could the command be incorrectly formatted?

Thank you in advance,

Jesse

code:

```
int test_commWriteRead()
{
  FT_HANDLE ftHandle;
  FT_STATUS ftStatus;
  ftStatus = FT_Open(0, &ftHandle);
  ftStatus |= FT_SetUSBParameters(ftHandle, 64, 64); // Set USB transfer sizes
  ftStatus |= FT_SetChars(ftHandle, false, 0, false, 0); // Disable event characters
  ftStatus |= FT_SetTimeouts(ftHandle, 5000, 5000); // Set read/write timeouts to 5 sec
  ftStatus |= FT_SetLatencyTimer(ftHandle, 16); // Latency timer at default 16ms
  ftStatus |= FT_SetFlowControl(ftHandle, FT_FLOW_NONE, 0x11, 0x13); // No flow control
  ftStatus |= FT_SetBaudRate(ftHandle, 9600);  // Baud rate = 9600
  ftStatus |= FT_SetDataCharacteristics(ftHandle, FT_BITS_8, FT_STOP_BITS_1, FT_PARITY_EVEN);
  if (ftStatus != FT_OK)
    printf("ftStatus not ok %d\n", ftStatus); //check for error
  else
  {
    //char data_out[12] = "Hello World";
    char data_out[4] = "014";
    DWORD w_data_len = 4;
    DWORD data_written;
    ftStatus = FT_Write(ftHandle, data_out, w_data_len, &data_written);
    if (ftStatus == FT_OK)
    {
      printf ("Write OK!\n");
      printf ("Bytes Written: %s \n", data_out);
      printf ("Data Out: %x \n", data_written);
      // FT_Write OK
    }
    else
    {
      printf ("Write Failed\n");
      // FT_Write Failed
      return 2;
    }

    DWORD EventDWord;
    DWORD TxBytes;
    DWORD RxBytes=10;
    DWORD BytesReceived;
    char RxBuffer[256];
    FT_GetStatus(ftHandle,&RxBytes,&TxBytes,&EventDWord);
    printf("Data in:  %s\n", RxBytes);
    if (RxBytes > 0) {
    ftStatus = FT_Read(ftHandle,RxBuffer,RxBytes,&BytesReceived);
    if (ftStatus == FT_OK) {
        // FT_Read OK
        printf("BytesReceived:  %s\n", BytesReceived);
    }
    else {
        // FT_Read Failed
        printf("ftStatus not ok %d\n", ftStatus);
    }
    }
  }
  ftStatus = FT_Close(ftHandle);
  printf("Press Return To End Program");
  getchar();
  return 0;
}
```

The resulting output is

```
Write OK!
Bytes Written: 014
Bytes Written: 4
Data in:  (null)
Press Return To End Program
```

I can test the command is working using 232Analyzer:

[image: example command using 232Analyser]

Comment: In 232 analyzer you're sending the decimal value 14, which has value 0x0E and is the "Shift Out" character.  In your code you're sending ascii data - an array of four chars filled with three bytes - the characters for '0', '1' and '4', or 0x30, 0x31, 0x34.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between binary zeros and ASCII character zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17975575/difference-between-binary-zeros-and-ascii-character-zero)

Comment: thank you, yes that would make a big difference, I changed the code to use: WORD data_out = 0x0E; however I still get no return value. I can post the new code, if this would be of help

Comment: 0x0E is a byte, not a word.  Slow down and pay attention to what you're doing.  You want to send one byte.  Check the length variable you're sending also.

Comment: thank you, yes, slow down. sending a single byte: byte data_out = 0x0E; and also w_data_len = 1; For some reason, RxBytes is always 0, if I read anyways I see 11 bytes, but this is a different issue now I think.

Comment: Make sure you're waiting enough time for the response.  RS-232 devices are slow.  When you write the bytes to a device it takes time for them to get there, time for them to be processed, time for a response to be generated, time for it to be transmitted, received, and then put into the receive buffer.  If you check right away the response won't be there yet.  Most RS-232 protocols tell you how much time you must wait before expecting a response.  Modern computers are extremely fast.  You have to build these waits into your protocol or use some other kind of sync (interrupts, IOCP, etc).

Comment: One simple way to manage the input is to poll `FT_GetStatus` for a fixed time (10msec poll for up to ~1sec, for example - it will depend on the device and the expected response time) while you are waiting for the response.  If the input buffer remains empty after a second then something has probably failed, but with this method you don't fail immediately if you check the input buffer before the response has had time to appear.